# VBA Query - Compare a string with the value of 2 rows

Tags: vba, ms-access

In order to find someone in DB, I need to compare a string value (which is his first and lastname) with 2 fields in DB. But I'm not really familiar with access sql syntax and I'm not sure how to do it.

I have tried different syntax but I can't find the appropriate one.

Here's the part of the code that is not working :

```vb
Private Sub Method()
   Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
   Dim strQuery As String`

   strQuery = "SELECT * " & _
      "FROM Import_SALESFORCE " & _
      "WHERE '" & strCounterPartyName & "' = [Person Account: First Name] + "
      & Space(1) & " + [Person Account: Lastname Name] "
   Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strQuery)
End Sub
```

Here's the error message I receive :
"Run-time error '3061':
Too few parameters. Expected 1."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This typically indicates a missing or misspelled field name.

My guess is LastName. So try:

```
"WHERE '" & strCounterPartyName & "' = [Person Account: First Name] + "
     & Space(1) & " + [Person Account: Last Name] "
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't noticed but I did a spelling mistake :D